# ArcMap, Data driven pages, raster layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, data-driven-pages, display

In ArcMap I'm trying to display specific **raster** layers using data driven pages and I got stuck. I have around fifty raster layers and corresponding pages in data driven pages. I only want specific layers on specific pages (one layer per one page is also acceptable). Normaly when I want to achive this with shp's or FC's I use page dafinition but here it's not possible. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you want the raster to be a base/background image or do you want a raster to show in the layout without vectors over it?  If the latter you can use this: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011951 or http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011969. I've had as many as 6 image boxes in a layout for inserted images using paths, and it is only when there is an image in the index layer for a page that an image "box" is filled.

Comment: My rasters are AIG(ArcGIS Binary Grids) and I want to use them like other layers, they show floodzones, I think second link from your comment (with raster catalog) may be the way but I need to test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Create Raster Catalogue -> Add field corresponding to data driven page -> use page definition query to match raster with DDP.

johns, Matthew thanks for repllies.

Comment: Mark the question as answered, unless you're waiting for more solutions. You can also click the up arrow if any of the answers and comments were useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of data driven pages and arcpy. If the names of the pages correspond somehow with the names of the raster layers, you could use something like this. In this example all raster layers are turned on, but you would want to compare the name to something that matches the page name or some other attribute of the index layer.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(strPath + strMXD + ".mxd")
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount):
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*"):
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
            if lyr.isRasterLayer:
                print lyr.name
                lyr.visible = True
```